# Unity 3D> PlasticSCM: What diff option does in PlasticSCM changesets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

In Unity 3D > PlasticSCM > ChangeSets: When you right click any changeset it shows "diff" option in context menu. What it does?

[Unity 3D > PlasticSCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2xK0.png)

Comment: Have you tried? ^^ to me it sounds like "Open your systems Diff tool and show the difference between this change and the current state" or something like that

Comment: Thanks, It should be marked as Answer